# Белка живет в дупле. Две белки выглянули из своих ...?

Tags: морфология

**`Дупло`** <sub>сущ., ср.рода, им.падеж, ед.число</sub> :  (there lives a squirrel).

Then:
Две белки выглянули из своих `[...]`(there will be a *pl.noun* in this field)
(a couple ways to answer ...)

- Дупл
- Дупел
- Дуплей
- ???

The question is: why have Russians faced difficulties in constructing such example?

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is `дупел`: [ru.wiktionary.org](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE).

Plural forms of some neuter nouns are rarely used in everyday language. Also significant part of the neuter nouns have no plural form at all. To be precise their plural form is the same as singular form.
For instance:

> метро
>   кофе
>   кино
>   пенсне
>   кимоно
>   ...

Comment: What's so hard about it? _Село, стекло, бедро, окно, поле, море, солнце_, etc., you name it.

Comment: @Quassnoi Oops, you are right. Edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: Funny that not all Russians know that дупел is the right form here. Btw, for дно Gen.pl. is доньев, that is unobvious as well.

Comment: @Justin McGuire: Its true, there are some weird words that not many people know how to say them in plural form. The most famous one: **кочерга** (an iron stick to mix coal in a fireplace for instance), I can guarantee no one knows for sure how to say it in plural :) many кочерг? кочерёг? кочерыжек? кочергей :))

Comment: @monstro You might be surprised but I'm native :). And I know this word but before this moment I wasn't even sure this form exists (now I looked up in wiktionary - кочерёг)

Comment: @Justin McGuire: Да и я тоже :)) Судя по Google Suggest, когда начинаешь печатать: много кочер, то становится понятно что для многих это всё таки загадка :)) http://i.imgur.com/RKStdSK.png

Comment: @monstro просто в реальной жизни редко употребляется, вот и звучит неестественно)